# SSRS Report shows a 2nd page which is blank

Tags: reporting-services

Hi I have a SSRS report with a Main Report and a Sub Report. The report is only one page and when I preview it for some reason it says 2 pages. The 2nd page is totally blank. I have checked the properties and 'Keep Together' is set to True.
I have also toggled between inches and centimeters which makes no difference still get a blank second page.

When I save as PDF it only displays one page, when I save to word 2 pages (2nd blank).

Below you can see the main and sub report properties, I even stripped everything off the sub report and left one text box and made the width and height considerably shorter than the main report but still get 2 pages when i preview. (See 'Preview of Main Report')

[Main Report Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmYQ6.png)
[Sub Report Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXtQ1.png)

[Preview of Main Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hizYD.png)

Thanks

Comment: One thing to check is that you do not have any report items sticking out of the margins.

Comment: How do i check that ? The 1st page shows all the report items as expected.

Comment: For example, you have 8.5 defined as the width and your push something out on the page to 8.58 (with or without content) then the overflow will start a new page.

Comment: Hi Ross i tried but still no joy i have added images above and stripped back the sub report but still get 2 pages.

Comment: Does 12.7 plus margins fit within your layout in word?

Comment: The margin is 0 so that should fit fine.